# Magento 2 product list quantity increment buttons

Tags: qty-increment

I have implemented the quantity increment buttons from https://magenticians.com/quantity-increment-decrement-magento-2/ and is working fine on product page. So I decided to implement it to list.phtml and buttons are displayed correctly but when I update quantity from a product all other quantities are updated too. Anyone knows how to update quantity for the item from I clicked the increment button?

I'm using the same code as Magenticians.
Thank you!

Comment: Is issue on product listing page right?

Comment: only for simple product or configurable

Comment: Yes, in product listing page. I've added the same code in list.phtml

Right now for simple products.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 product listing page add quantity increase and decrease buttons

> > Add below HTML code in form of add to cart section

```
<div class="field qty">
    <div class="control qty-change">
      <button class="decreaseqty">-</button>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="qty"
               id="qty"
               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
               />

        <span class="qty-label"> 1 ITEMS </span>
      <button class="increaseqty">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> > Add below jQuery in listing page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
    jQuery(".increaseqty").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var qty = jQuery(this).closest("div.control").find("input");
        var newqty = parseInt(qty.val())+parseInt(1);
        qty.val(newqty);
        var val = qty.val();
        var label = jQuery.mage.__('ITEMS');
        var changeQty = parseInt(val) + label;
        qtyLabel = jQuery(this).closest("div.control").find("span");
        jQuery(qtyLabel).text(changeQty);
        return false;
    });

    jQuery(".decreaseqty").click(function(){
        var qty = jQuery(this).closest("div.control").find("input");
        var newqty = parseInt(qty.val())-parseInt(1);
        if(newqty < 1){
            return false;
        }
        qty.val(newqty);
        var val = qty.val();
        var label = jQuery.mage.__('ITEMS');
        var changeQty = parseInt(val) + label;
        qtyLabel = jQuery(this).closest("div.control").find("span");
        jQuery(qtyLabel).text(changeQty);
        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I spend few weeks to find this solutions.Al last find this one.Thanks @Baharuni Asif

Answer (score 0):

add below code in addtocart.phtml

```
<button class="action tocart primary decrease  qty_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" data-bind="click: decreaseQty"><span class="minus"></span></button>
    <div class="input-text qty">
        <input id="qty_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"
               name="qty"
               readonly
               data-bind="value: qty()"
               type="number"
               value="<?= $defaultQty ?>"
               readonly
               size="4"
               style="width:50px"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
               class="input-text"
               data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
        />

    </div>
    <button class="action tocart primary increase" data-bind="click: increaseQty"><span class="Plus"></span></button>
```

create js file like qty_incr_decr.js and add below code

```
define([
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

], function (ko, Component,$,customerData) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({

```
    minicartSelector: '[data-block="minicart"]',
    addToCartButtonSelector: '.action.tocart',
    messagesSelector: '[data-placeholder="messages"]',
    updateCartUrl : BASE_URL+'NameSpace_Module/cart/addToCart',
    ajaxRequest: [],

    initialize: function () {
        //initialize parent Component
        this._super();
        this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));
        var self = this;
    },
    decreaseQty: function() {

        var product_id = this.productId;

        if($('#qty_'+product_id).val() == 0) {
            this.qty($('#qty_'+product_id).val());
        }

        var newQty = parseFloat(this.qty()) - this.qtyIncrement;

        if (newQty < 0)
        {
            newQty = 0;

            return;
        }

        this.abortAjaxRequest(product_id);

        if(newQty < parseFloat(this.minCartQty)) {
            newQty = 0;
        }

        var availableQty = window.atob(this.saleableQty);

        if(availableQty < newQty) {
            newQty = parseFloat(availableQty);
        }

        this.addRemoveDeleteClass(newQty);
        $('.selling-format-qty-'+product_id).text(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));


        this.qty(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));
        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',newQty);

        this.submitForm();

    },
    increaseQty: function() {
        var product_id = this.productId;
        if($('#qty_'+product_id).val() == 0) {
            this.qty($('#qty_'+product_id).val());
        }

        var availableQty = window.atob(this.saleableQty);

        if(availableQty < parseFloat(this.qty()) + this.qtyIncrement) {
            return;
        }


        this.abortAjaxRequest(product_id);

        var newQty = parseFloat(this.qty()) + this.qtyIncrement;

        if(newQty < this.minCartQty) {
            newQty = this.minCartQty;
        }

        this.addRemoveDeleteClass(newQty);
        $('.selling-format-qty-'+product_id).text(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));


        this.qty(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));

        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',newQty);

        var self = this;

        this.submitForm();
    },

    submitForm: function() {

        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;

        this.ajaxSubmit($('[data-role='+tmpId+']'));
    },

    /**
     * @param {jQuery} form
     */
    ajaxSubmit: function (form) {
        var  formData;

        //$(this.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');

        var self = this;
        var product_id = this.productId;
        formData = new FormData(form[0]);

        this.ajaxRequest[product_id] = $.ajax({
            url: this.updateCartUrl,
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            /** @inheritdoc */
            success: function (res) {

                if(form.find('.cart-item-id').val() == '') {
                    form.find('[name="item_id"]').val(res.item_id);
                }

                if(self.qty() ==0) {
                    form.find('.cart-item-id').val('')
                }


            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            error: function (res) {

            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            complete: function (res) {
                if (res.state() === 'resolved') {
                    var response = res.responseJSON;
                    if(typeof $('#cart-item-'+response.item_id+'-qty').val() != "undefined"
                        && eval($('#cart-item-'+response.item_id+'-qty').val()) != eval(self.qty()))
                    {
                        self.ajaxSubmit(form);
                    } else {
                        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },

    disableAddToCartButton: function () {
        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;
        var form = $('[data-role='+tmpId+']');
        var addToCartButton = form.find('.action.tocart');
        addToCartButton.attr("disabled", true);
    },

    enableAddToCartButton: function () {
        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;
        var form = $('[data-role='+tmpId+']');
        var addToCartButton = form.find('.action.tocart');
        addToCartButton.attr("disabled", false);
    },

    abortAjaxRequest: function (product_id) {
        if(this.ajaxRequest[product_id] != null) {
            this.ajaxRequest[product_id].abort();
            this.ajaxRequest[product_id] = null;
        }
    },

    addRemoveDeleteClass: function (newQty) {
        $('.qty_'+this.productId).removeClass('delete-qty');
        if(newQty == this.qtyIncrement) {
            $('.qty_'+this.productId).addClass('delete-qty');
        }
    }

});
```

});

then create addtocart controller and add logic for add product to cart.